# SpringData JPA Hibernate, trying to save a new nested object

Tags: json, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have a nested object like this

```
public class Chart {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private long chart_id;

   @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name="chart_id")
   private Set<ChartGroup> chartGroups;
        /* ..other attributes.. */
}

public class ChartGroup {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private long group_id;
   private long chart_id;

       @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name="group_id")
   private ChartYData chartYData;
         /* ..other attributes.. */
 }

 public class ChartYData {

   @Id
   private long group_id;

   private String yData;
  }
```

I have REST services where are used to fetch and save/update this data. After fetching the data for a specific chart I save all JSON data in a javascript object. User can delete or modify groups in a chart or he can add new groups. I am sending full chart object to the server to be saved. No call is made when you add a new group or delete an old group. The problem arises when user adds new group. In my JSON the values are like this
[image: Post Data JSON]

When I try to update the CHART object, it gives me MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`chartpro`.`chart_ydata`, CONSTRAINT `fk_ydata_to_group` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `chart_group` (`group_id`)

Is there a way to update my chart object as a whole? I mean the JPA should add ChartGroup and then add ChartYData with the newly created group_id

It gives me same error even when I send following JSON, (with group_id=null for new groups)

```
  ChartGroups : [{/* data for previously present Chart groups (works fine) */},{
    chartYData :
 { 
            ydata : "ydata",
            group_id : null
          } 
  chart_id:1
  group_id:null
 }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem that you have to set the group_id in ChartYData entities manually as you are not sending group_id with json object, or handle it by javascript to add group_id to ChartYData before sending it.

Comment: I am still getting same exception, now I am sending JSON with group_id=null for new groups.

Comment: it should not be null try to persist ChartGroup first then get group_id and set it in ChartYData then persist it